# how to use result of first observable into next observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this method:

```js
 zip(
  this.$one.getOne(id)
     .pipe(switchMap(oneResult => {
        return this.$two.getTwo(oneResult.id)
      }))
     .pipe(switchMap(twoResult => {
        // Here I Would like to use the **oneResult** as argument to the $three observable too.
        return this.$three.getThree(oneResult.id)
     })),
   this.$four.getFour()
 ).subscribe(zipResult => {
     [getTwoResult, getThreeResult]
 }
```

How do I pass the `$one` Observable result to `$two` Observable and `$hree` observable? I can just get it on the first switchMap.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You can chain `$hree` with `$one` or use `share()` operator...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an use `map` on the `switchMap` to create a "resultSelector". [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html#example-3-using-a-resultselector-function) has a resultSelector function that can be used to create the same effect, but this may get deprecated in future versions of RxJS in lieu of using `map` as the below answer demonstrates. You'd effectively be packaging `oneResult` and `twoResult` into an object or array for use in the second `switchMap`. You could keep doing this as far down the stream as you'd need. It would look like something like this (I've added delays to simulate API calls):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  getOne(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return of('foo').pipe(delay(1000));
  }

  getTwo(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return of('bar').pipe(delay(1000));
  }

  getThree(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return of('baz').pipe(delay(1000));
  }

  getFour(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return of('foobar').pipe(delay(1000));
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    zip(
      this.getOne('foo').pipe(
        switchMap(oneResult =>
          this.getTwo(oneResult).pipe(
            map(twoResult => ({ oneResult, twoResult }))
          )
        ),
        switchMap(oneTwoResult => {
          console.log(oneTwoResult);
          return this.getThree(oneTwoResult.oneResult);
        })
      ),
      this.getFour('foobar')
    )
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
  }
}
```

Using `resultSelector` function of `switchMap`:

```
zip(
  this.getOne('foo').pipe(
    switchMap(oneResult =>
      this.getTwo(oneResult),
      (oneResult, twoResult) => ({ oneResult, twoResult })
    ),
    switchMap(oneTwoResult => {
      console.log('oneTwoResult: ', oneTwoResult);
      return this.getThree(oneTwoResult.oneResult)
    })
  ),
  this.getFour('foobar')
)
.subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qptare) showing this functionality in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot! Just one question:
You said that ` You could keep doing this as far down the stream as you'd need` . So if suppose the `$four` observable is dependent on the `resultOne`, I need to create a map on the `$three` observable too, to pass the `resultOne`down?

Comment: Correct, that would be most straightforward approach. Otherwise an operator like forkJoin can be used. Thanks!

Comment: forkJoin i just imagine on the place of the zip operator, is that what you mean?

Comment: I'd have to experiment, but yes effectively remove zip and forkJoin after one emits, forking 2+3 and 4.

Comment: I just found this answer, but found out that the `resultSelector` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-result-selector-migration). I use `forkJoin` instead, though the recommended solution is using another `pipe` with `map`.